# JQUERY ASP.NET MVC - ReferenceError : Index is not defined at eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, each, referenceerror

I'm new to jquery and I'm stuck on this reference issue for days now. I do know that this might be caused due to not referencing the correct path and so on but I have tried everything from getting the plugins first and checking every js file directory and still cannot figure out whats the issue here:

custom.js:

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var arr = ['1', '2']
    $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
        console.log(value)
    });
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $("#").show();

    $("#@ViewBag.id").click(function () {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});

})(jQuery);
```

Everything works fine except the $.each function where it throws error:
**ReferenceError: index is not defined↵    at eval**  and the same goes to value.
My _Layout page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="box-shadow:none">
<head></head>
<body style="padding-top:0px">

@RenderBody()
<hr />
<footer></footer>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/custom.js"></script>
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
 </body>
 </html>
```

This has been driving me nuts, someone please help!!

Thanks in advance...

**UPDATE**
As per @CarstenLøvboAndersen,I just moved my debugger inside the each function and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Why have you included 3 different versions of jquery?

Comment: Was just being extra sure I guess..didn't want to leave any ground uncovered

Comment: Ironically including multiple versions will cause more problems than it solves. I'd suggest removing at least 2. I'd also suggest using the latest version, 3.3.1, assuming you don't need to support IE8 and lower.

Comment: @ReynoldDmello Does it give you an error in the console or just `index is not defined` when you debug, because there is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes I get the error when I debug. I agree there is nothing wrong with the code somehow its giving a reference error and skips the each loop

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan As you mentioned , I removed the 2 files and used the latest one: 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script> still the same

Comment: Y@ReynoldDmello You code works, move the debug inside your `.each` and you can see that it has values and is defined, You debugger show it as `Not defined` because you never actually goes inside the `.each`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks so much , this works for me. Can't believe just a simple debugger switch  solved this ..silly me. Thanks Again..